Exponentiaion with Church numerals
I was reading about exponentiation in lambda calculus on Wikipedia and found the expression
\begin{equation}
\lambda x. \lambda y. y\; x
\end{equation}
and on the Church encoding page it states
\begin{equation}
n\, m\, f = m^n f
\end{equation}
since is the definition of a Church numeral $n$ with $f \to  m$, $ x \to f$, which I believe I understand.
However I also understand $m^n$ to mean $m$ applied $n$ times ( $m(m(m(...)))$ $n$ times ) but $m$ itself is $f$ applied $m$ times ( $f(f(f(...)))$ $m$ times) so $m^n$ would be $f(f(f(...)))$ $m \times n$ times, which would be the product of $m$ and $n$. On the Church encoding page they do describe multiplication as $ (f^m)^n \,x $ so I believe my assumption that $m = f^m$ in the above formula is incorrect, but I can't see why.

$m=f^m$ is incorrect. Instead it's $m\ f=f^m.$

You copied Wikipedia wrong: it says $n\ m\ f = m^n\ f$, not $m\ n\ f$.

I'm not sure what your question is. Have you tried working through a concrete example, like $\beta$-reducing $3^2$?

@md2perpe Thank you I understand now

@NaïmFavier Thank you, the example helped a lot. I was approaching the problem too abstractly, but think I understand it now.


On the Church encoding page they do describe multiplication as $(f^m)^nx$ so I believe my assumption that $m=f^m$ in the above formula is incorrect, but I can't see why.

$(f^m)^nx$ would be $n$ compositions of, $m$ compositions of $f$, applied to $x$, which is : $(\bar n\,(\bar m\,f))\,x$.
Thus multiplication is: $\lambda n.\lambda m.\lambda f.\lambda x.n(mf)x $

As for exponentiation:
Lambda calculus terms are left-associated unless parenthesis indicate otherwise.
That is: $\bar n\,\bar m\,f\,x$ is implicitly $((\bar n\,\bar m)\,f)\,x$, which would be  $f^{m^n}x$.
Compositions of $f$ applied to $x$ by a count of $n$ compositions of $m$.
$\qquad\begin{align}\bar n\,\bar m\,f\,x &=_\delta(\lambda a.\lambda b. a^n(b))\,\bar m\, f\,x\\&=_\beta (\lambda b.\bar m^n(b))\,f\,x\\&=~(\lambda b.\underset{{n\textsf{ compositions}}}{\underline{\bar m(\bar m\ldots}}(b)))\,f\,x\\&=~(\lambda b.(\ldots((b\underset{n\text{ exponents}}{\underline{)^m)^m)^\ldots}}))\,f\,x\\&=~(\lambda b.\underset{\small n\text{ multiplications}}{(b)^{\underline{m\times m\times\ldots}}})\,f\,x\\&=~(\lambda b.b^{m^n})\,f\,x\\&=_\beta f^{m^n}x\end{align}$
